# SQL query to display column value till specific character (like .(dot) in my case)

Tags: sql

Friends

I need help to write a SQL query that display the column value till it ecountered . in column value. 
Column datatype is varchar and database is SQL server.

ex.

```
column_value 
FRY    
aaaa.bb    
fbf.bb    
rrjf.rft        

`i need output in below format`
column_value  
FRY     
aaaa    
fbf    
rrjf    

I would appreaciate for any pointer on this.
```

Comment: It helps to know what flavor of SQL...  Is this MSSQL?  Oracle?  Which version?

Comment: I am using SQL server

Answer (score 1):

You could use the`left`,`charindex`and`substring`functions to accomplish this:

Example done with SQL Fiddle:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/377f7/3)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    ([column_value] varchar(8))
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    ([column_value])
VALUES
    ('FRY'),
    ('aaaa.bb'),
    ('fbf.bb'),
    ('rrjf.rft')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select 
  left(
      column_value, 
      case 
        when charindex('.', column_value, 0) = 0 then len(column_value) 
        else charindex('.', column_value, 0) -1 
      end
  ) as Trimmed_column
from table1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/377f7/3/0)**:

```
| TRIMMED_COLUMN |
|----------------|
|            FRY |
|           aaaa |
|            fbf |
|           rrjf |
```

Comment: thanks guys i have tried above suggestion and it worked to some extent. I got error when it was dealing with number. Column datatype is vachar though it has some values in digits as well.

Column_value
abc
sre
123
hfhf.bb

Error msg reads:
Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.

Comment: @user3375857 Could you update the original question to include the column value you get an error for? The only arithmetic the query does is the calculation of the length, so you shouldn't get that error at all (and I don't when using the value `123`)

Answer (score 0):

try this

LEFT(column_value, CHARINDEX('.', column_value))

Comment: This will miss all rows that doesn't contain a dot.